# Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1 in laravel webhook api for stripe

Tags: php

I found an error **Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1** during the test a webhook event named **invoice.created**. There is a strange that it's working fine in a local server but not working on a live server. Below is my code:-

```
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
        $event_json = json_decode($input);
        switch ($event_json->type) {
            case 'invoice.created'
             print_r($event_json);die;    
            break;
         }
```

Comment: Do you have used "localhost" or IP used in setup url in endpoint for local host setup?

Please make sure to check if you used SSL(https) at your live server, then your end point link with https not http becuase may be http is redirecting to https due to htaccess setting. So post response not get after redirecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BhavinThummar. I made a mistake with SSL. It's working fine now.

Comment: Okay then you can give up vote to my comment if my comment is really help to solve your issue Or you can tick my answer as right.

Comment: I got the same type of error by filtering access to the server via IPs from the apache configuration. 
I added the IPs of the stripe servers displayed in my logs /var/log/apache2/error.log and now I don't get any error. It must be the apache error message that is not in the right format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure to check if you used SSL(HTTPS) at your live server,

Then your end point link should be with HTTPS not HTTP because may be HTTP is redirecting to HTTPS due to .htaccess route setting So post response not get after redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The fault was, that webhook link was without `www`. When I add it, it started to work.