# Stripe Webhooks Error 503 Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1

Tags: encoding, stripe-payments, webhooks

I setup a stripe webhook with signature verification just as recommended by stripe:

```
<?php

logme("Secure connection: ".isSecure());
logme("I was called at:".time());

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_ff...');
$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_Ky...';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');

if($payload) {
//request body is set
} else {
//request body is not set
    exit();
}

$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];

$event = null;


try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );

} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

http_response_code(200);

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'event1':
    // do something 
    break;
    
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
        logme('Received unknown event type ' . $event->type);
}


function logme($msg){

    $log_file = "error.txt";
// logging error message to given log file
    error_log($msg."\n-\n", 3, $log_file);
}
function isSecure() {
    return
        (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
        || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
}
```

At stripe dashboard I created a webhook with https://example.org/path/to/webhook.php but if I fire invoice.paid webhook in test mode I receive the following error:

```
Test-Webhook-Error: 503 
Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Is anyone familiar with this kind of error?

---

**Update** 
It seems to depend on the type of event that is triggered. E.g. plan.deleted works and payment_intent.succeeded does not

Answer (score 2):

To anyone still facing this issue, I recently came up against it and finally realised that it was due to me missing the trailing slash off the webhook endpoint....there's a couple of hours well spent!

Comment: Thank you for saving me a week or month with that!

Answer (score 1):

This error does not appear to be coming from the signature verification, but rather somewhere else in your request/network stack. Note that the error you throw in the `try {}` is `withStatus(403)` (not 503). Can you provide more detailed logging from your server to identify where this fails?

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119582/invalid-encoding-iso-8859-1-in-laravel-webhook-api-for-stripe/55136738) and the solution being connected to a HTTP -> HTTPS redirect. Ensure your configured endpoint is going directly to HTTPS and that your SSL certificates are responding correctly.

I also see you are calling `$event = $request->getParsedBody();` at the start of your handler even before signature checking, which can something cause problems with the body data being manipulated (the signature verification requires the raw body of the request).

Comment: I've just updated the code. The new version is above. In Stripes backend the webhook endpoint is at https and the `.htaccess` redirects every request to https

Comment: And to be sure I deleted the whole `.htaccess` to see if there are any interferences caused by this , but same error

Comment: Sure, but again you're saying there is a 503 error but there is not code that would raise that shown. Do you have server logs showing the source of the error?

Comment: (sorry i failed to add the link to the other question, edited)

Comment: I receive the error 503 in stripes backend. I logged the `$payload` and `headers` in a txt-file and it seems all fine.

Comment: The error must be something on the "way back". The script works totally fine, as I see in the logs. But for any reason stripe doesn't receive the `http_response_code 200`

Comment: If I use the stripe CLI and trigger the webhook I still get 503 but the `POST-data` from stripe is received successfully. If I fire a test webhook in Stripe backend I only receive the 503 and no data is logged.

Comment: Okay, I think it has something to do with the type of trigger. Some work perfectly fine and others like payment_intent.succeeded make the `Error 503`

Comment: can you share the contents of `handlePaymentIntentSucceeded`? If the issue is specific to that (and maybe some other types), then it seems likely for the issue to be inside those handlers.

Comment: `handlePaymentIntentSucceeded` is still an empty function. If I try to log the `$paymentIntent`-Parameter it doesn't work. If the `503` error occurs the whole script seems to fail.

Comment: And what about the handlers for one of the working types? What do they do? Do you need to send a success response in the payment intent handler? ie, how is the request being responded do at the end?

Comment: Well I first wanna to make the webhook generally work and than apply the necessary functions.

Comment: Im just wondering about the fact that some (most) trigger work and some others (essential for me) does not. And they are treated all the same way. In the current version I just log the event type.

Comment: My point is that it is not clear how you end up with a 503 given the code displayed. The only Stripe-specific code is `\Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent` which is inside a try/catch, and does not throw a 503. This must be coming from your own code/stack. Can you trace where the failure happens via logging? Are you getting to the `http_response_code(200)`?

Comment: I post the complete file so you possible spot the error. Because I can't see anything wrong