# Why do some stripe webhook events trigger error and others do not?

Tags: events, triggers, stripe-payments, webhooks

Some stripe events trigger a `503 Error` at my webhhok endpoint in php.

E.g.: If i test `payment_intent.succeeded` or `payment_method.attached` in stripe backend I receive

```
Test-Webhook-Error: 503
Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

If i test `payment_intent.created` everything works fine.

`HTTPS` works properly.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your recent question about this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458444/stripe-webhooks-error-503-invalid-encoding-iso-8859-1/66458901

Comment: Yes, kind of. I thought it would be nice to have a conclusion

Comment: But seems to be a rare problem. Unfortunately